# Dlvr.it with WebSub (Pubsubhubbub) feed takes up to 5 minutes to post new updates

Tags: facebook, rss, websub

I'm using dlvr.it to automatically posts RSS feeds to social media. According to the article mentioned below the feeds should publish in real time, but it takes up to 5 minutes:

https://support.dlvrit.com/hc/en-us/articles/200402424-Enabling-real-time-updates-with-dlvr-it

Is it possible to publish feeds on social media in real time without the latency of 5 minutes?

Feed: https://dev.rotoballer.com/player-news/feed?sport=nfl

Answer (score 0):

dlvr.it posts items immediately (plus some minor internal processing time) upon receipt of the PuSH update.

The speed of the updates depends entirely upon how quickly the PuSH hub is notified of the update by the publishing site, how quickly the update is pulled by the hub, and how quickly the hub distributes the update to subscribers.